# Asymptotic normality: do the convergences hold?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a sequence $Z_n$ of random variables with mean $\mu_n$ and variance $\sigma_n^2$. Suppose we know that there exist constants $a_n$ and $b_n(>0)$ such that $\dfrac{Z_n-a_n}{b_n}\to\mathcal N(0,1)$ in distribution.

Then, is it true that $\dfrac{\sigma_n^2}{b_n^2}\to1$ and $\dfrac{\mu_n-a_n}{b_n}\to0$?

Can you please give a proof or point me to the relevant literature?

Comment: Any relation to my question '[Does central limit theorem still hold if bounds change?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541674)' ?

Comment: @BCLC Actually, no. This question was regarding general asymptotic normality, not CLT or quantiles. Your question could be answered using Polya's theorem.

Comment: Oh thanks Landon Carter. Post as answer?  (Wait [this one: Polya Enumeration](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyaEnumerationTheorem.html) ? Or [this: Polya criteria for characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions)?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessarily true. Let $Z$ be a standard normal variable and $\Phi(x)$ be its CDF. Think of the following sequence $Z_n$:
$$
Z_n=\begin{cases}
Z, &\text{if $Z\le n$,}\\
1/(1-\Phi(n)), &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, this sequence converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,1)$ (so, $a_n=0$, $b_n=1$). But its mean is
$$
E(Z_n)=\Phi(n)E(Z\mid Z\le n)+(1-\Phi(n))/(1-\Phi(n))\to1
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Is it however true that $\dfrac{\sigma_n^2}{b_n^2}\to1$ holds?

Comment: It's a very simple example. You can construct one where the variance ratio won't tend to one as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, in your example itself, the variance does not converge to $1$. It blows up. Thanks for answering.

Comment: This is bad news for me. I hoped that at least if we have Normal distribution, we have some sort of moment convergence. I essentially wanted something like $Z_n\to N(0,1)$ implies $E(Z_n)\to0,Var(Z_n)\to1$. Now I do not know how to get anywhere. But to be honest, I need to be able to say such things.

Comment: @LandonCarter Under further assumptions like uniform integrability, you can infer such things. It would probably be for the best if you open a new question where you describe your *original* problem.